# How to select the first n elements in array of XPath elements

Tags: html, xpath

I have an Web Page with multiple cells like in the example and I would like to select first 50 checkboxes...

```
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
```

I tried it with XPATH like:

```
.//*/td[@class="col-xs-0"]//input[@ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);"][position() <= 50]
```

but it gives me all nodes on the page, I need first 50... Where is the mistake? Thanks.

Comment: On a first glance your example looks correct. Please expand your question with an example where the problem can be reproduced... selecting e.g. just the first two nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `position()` gives the index of each iterable with respect to its parent, the `input` elements you are getting from your xpath are relative to `td` and there are no 50 `input` elements underneath each `td`.

Instead the following xpath would work for you :

`//td[@class="col-xs-0" and count(child::*[name()="input"][@type="checkbox" and @ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);"])>0][position()<=50]`

This xpath works by first getting all `td`s that match the criteria and then on finding position.

Sample input :

```
<root>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="radio" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="radio" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="radio" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
<td class="col-xs-0">
<input type="radio" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>
</root>
```

the xpath `//td[@class="col-xs-0" and count(child::*[name()="input"][@type="checkbox" and @ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);"])>0][position()<=3]` returns :

```
Element='<td class="col-xs-0">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>'
Element='<td class="col-xs-0">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>'
Element='<td class="col-xs-0">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>'
```

where as the xpath `//td[@class="col-xs-0" and count(child::*[name()="input"][@type="radio" and @ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);"])>0][position()<=2]` returns :

```
Element='<td class="col-xs-0">
  <input type="radio" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>'
Element='<td class="col-xs-0">
  <input type="radio" ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);" />
</td>'
```

Comment: //td[@class="col-xs-0" and count(child::*[name()="input"][@type="checkbox" and @ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);"])>0][position()<=50] - returns me 0 nodes... I can rebuild the xpath to //*[@type="checkbox" and @ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);"][position()<=50] this one suppose to select all nodes and return 50, but it returns 100 for now (I have a 100 rows in the table)

Comment: I created a sample xml with multiple `td` elements I got the elements as I desired

Comment: Again your new xpath will give `input` elements and position() on them will not take effect , there are no 50 elements underneath `td`

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/n3jycHYYHoLguPnHjj7DzlbAh54ODF  - still doesn't work for me...

Comment: the same for //td[@class="col-xs-0" and count(child::*[name()="input"][@type="radio" and @ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);"])>0][position()<=2]

Comment: I just tried to rebuild the query to select 50 td and after their checkboxes, but it still gives me 100 records  .//td[position() <= 50]/input[@type="checkbox" and @ng-click="selectedRun(record.file_name, record.run_status);"]

Comment: First of all you are using FirePath, and you should have mentioned that in your question. But I tested your xpath using firepath, it works for me. Something wrong with your html. Post complete html.